# How to use regular expression to match a string include transverse line?

Tags: python, django

I want to use dynamic url in Django to match my dynamic href in template, which is assembled from addresses, such as below:

```
../details/0-TIFFANY-CRES
../details/1-Airport-PKY
```

I am a layman of regular expression, the current url I want to match is :

```
<pre>

    path('details/(?P<addline>[-\w]+)/$', details),

</pre>
```

it didn't work(of course).

In addition, I want to use the address in the urls in my views, how can I convert this address to my new views function?

How can I match the urls? If there is any unclear parts, please tell me and I will try to explain more.

Comment: You need to use a quantifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import the module for regex in Django 2.0 like:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/2003/', views.special_case_2003),
    re_path(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
    re_path(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive),
    re_path(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.article_detail),
]
```

[More info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions)

The new address will be the name of the functions or class you assign, in your case `path('details/[-\w]', details),` `details` is the function and you can get the parameters with the name assigned to the regex group `re_path(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),` in this example the regex group name is `?P<year>`

Comment: so in views def, code: def details(request, addline):  . I can get the addline by ?P<addline> ?

Comment: @YuchenHuang yep

Comment: Actually I have voted up, but it remind me I have less 15 reputation